# Calling MySQL functions in Lithium

Tags: php, mysql, crud, lithium

How it's possible to call MySQL function (like **GeomFromText()** or **SELECT AS**) in the [Lithium Framework's](http://www.lithify.me/) CRUD? Using *database->read()* is to inconvenient (I often change the database columns) and including the function in the variable's value only ends up being escaped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried putting the function in the fields option?

For example, I do this:

```
Model::first(array(
    'fields' => 'max(id)'
));
```

To clarify, in your query, try this (i have not tested this):

```
Model::first(array(
     'fields' => array('field1 as myField', 'GeomFromText("POINT(x y)") as geom')
));
```

Comment: No, thanks for the advice! How do make a **SELECT AS** or **GEOMFROMTEXT** query, then?