# In Lithium Is it possible to use db specific functions in Model::create?

Tags: lithium

Similar to what you can do in a find call: [Calling MySQL functions in Lithium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000727/calling-mysql-functions-in-lithium)

I would like to be able to do this:

```
$result = Model::create(array(
   'geoFunctionResult' => "GeometryFromText('POINT({$this->request->data['longitude']} {$this->request->data['latitude']})')",
));
```

In this case the value needs to be a literal part of the generated SQL so that it executes as a db function, then the result of the function is the actual value inserted.

Comment: What's the problem do you want to solve? Stop by #li3 on IRC

Answer (score 0):

`Model::create()` returns an instance of your Model class which is not yet saved to a database.
Calling `$instance->save()` will do.

Your question doesn't make sense.